# Noether's normalization finite transitivity proof

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Assume $R$ is a finitely generated $k$ algebra. Then there exists $u_1,...,u_d\in R$ such that $u_1,...,u_d$ are algebraically indepdendent and $R$ is finitely generated over $k[u_1,...,u_d]$.

Proof attempt:
Choose $s_1,...,s_n$ such that $R=k[s_1,...,s_n]$. If $s_1,...,s_n$ are algebraically indpendent we are done. Assume else then $s_n$ is an integral element of $k[s_1,...,s_n]$ over $k[s_1,..,s_{n-1}]$. That is, $k[s_1,...,s_{n-1}]\subseteq k[s_1,...,s_n]$ is an integral extension. Hence as it is finitely generated, it is a finite extension. So if $s_1,...,s_{n-1}$ are algebraically independent, we are done. Otherwise $s_{n-1}$ is an integral element of $k[s_1,...,s_{n-1}]$ over $k[s_1,...,s_{n-2}]$. Hence, $k[s_1,....,s_{n-2}]\subseteq k[s_1,...,s_{n-1}]$ is a finite extension. This process terminates; otherwise $k[s_1]$ is a finite extension of $k$. Hence by finite transitivity, $R$ is finite over $k$.

How does one complete the proof?

Comment: Why do you think that $s_n$ needs to be integral over $k[s_1, \dotsc, s_{n-1}]$? For example in $R = k[x,y,z,w] / (xy + zw)$, why would on of the variables be integral over the rest?

Comment: @red_trumpet We may assume that a non-zero polynomial in $k[x_1,...,x_n]$ is of the form $a_mx_n^m+a_{m-1}x_n^{m-1}+...+a_0$ where $a_0,...,a_{m-1}$ are polynomials over $k[x_1,...,x_{n-1}]$ and $a_m$ is a non-zero element in $k$.

Comment: I don't get your point. How would you apply your proof-recipe to my example ring?